# Jquery File Upload plugin does not work drang and drop of file in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, blueimp

I have a code where I can drag and drop files when using Chrome or firefox.  However, when I use IE 11, when I drop a file, the browser opens the file instead of uploading it.  I can't seem to find a good example on how to implement this that works in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the WordPress source. I know they have a drag-and-drop media upload feature that is working great in IE11.